# Kubernetes operator metrics endpoint TLS configuration

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubernetes-operator

I am trying to configure metrics endpoint over https

```golang
mgr, err := ctrl.NewManager(ctrl.GetConfigOrDie(), ctrl.Options{
        Scheme: scheme,
        Metrics: server.Options{
            SecureServing: true,
            BindAddress:   metricsAddr,
            ExtraHandlers: map[string]http.Handler{
                fmt.Sprintf("/%s/metrics", GetNamespace()): metrics.GetCustomMetricsHandlerInstance(),
            },
            FilterProvider: func(c *rest.Config, httpClient *http.Client) (server.Filter, error) {},
            CertDir: "",
            CertName: "",
            KeyName: "",
            TLSOpts: []func(*tls.Config){},
        },
// ... other configurations
})
```

If I don't provide certificates at startup, the server will generate self-signed certs (reference: [self-signed cert generation code](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/controller-runtime/blob/main/pkg/metrics/server/server.go#L302)). My main concern is providing a way to load updated certificates from secrets once they are created. Unfortunately, at startup, I don't have access to secrets.

I'm wondering if there's a way to load certificates later from secrets, perhaps using this function `[]func(*tls.Config){}`, or if there's another recommended approach. Additionally, would I need to reload the HTTPS server in any way?